# Resize UIToolbar will be reject in App Store?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

i think it not use private API , it will be rejected?

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = 
CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.x, 
self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y, 
self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width, 60);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apple says u wont by programatically.

Guidelines

Use a toolbar to provide a set of actions users can take in the current context.

Use a toolbar to give people a selection of frequently used commands that make sense in the current context. An alternative is to put a segmented control in a toolbar to give people access to different perspectives on your application’s data or to different application modes (for usage guidelines, see “Segmented Control”).

Maintain a hit target area of at least 44 x 44 points for each toolbar item. If you crowd toolbar items too closely together, people have difficulty tapping the one they want.

Use system-provided toolbar items according to their documented meaning. See “Standard Buttons for Use in Toolbars and Navigation Bars” for more information. If you decide to create your own toolbar items, see “Icons for Navigation Bars, Toolbars, and Tab Bars” for advice on how to design them.

Try to avoid mixing plain style (borderless) and bordered toolbar items in the same toolbar. You can use either style in a toolbar, but mixing them does not usually look good.

Specify the color or translucency of a toolbar, when appropriate. If you want the toolbar to coordinate with the overall look of your app, you can specify a custom color. You can make a toolbar translucent if you want to encourage people to pay more attention to the content underneath the bar. Make sure the toolbar customization you do is consistent with the look of the rest of your application. If you use a translucent toolbar, for example, don’t combine it with an opaque navigation bar. And, avoid changing the color or translucency of the toolbar in different screens in the same orientation.

On iPhone, take into account the automatic change in toolbar height that occurs on device rotation. In particular, make sure your custom toolbar icons fit well in the thinner bar that appears in landscape orientation. **Don’t specify the height of a toolbar programmatically.**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW33